# How to select a drop down item from a combobox in a webbrowser control using a matching combobox control on a user form in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to select a dropdown item from a combobox in a webbrowser control using a combobox on my user form using VB.NET.  I've been researching this issue for the last couple of days and have tried every solution I could find so far, but to no avail.

Here's the snippet from the HTML page that's loaded in the webbrowser control which I've called "screenerwebbrowser":

```html
<select name="ctl00$bodyPlaceHolder$UniverseList" id="ctl00_bodyPlaceHolder_UniverseList" onchange="SBT.Util.Window.reload({UniverseID:this.value, PageViewID:this.value}, true);">
  <option selected="selected" value="FOUSA">Mutual Fund</option>
  <option value="STUSA">Stock</option>
  <option value="FCUSA">Closed-end Fund</option>
  <option value="FEUSA">Exchange Traded Fund</option>
  <option value="VAFTUSA">First Trust VA Subaccount</option>
  <option value="FIUSA">First Trust Unit Investment Trust</option>
</select>
```

The userform has a button called ScreenerCheckBox which makes the webbrowser control called ScreenerWebBrowser visible and loads the website with the combobox I'm trying to control. Below is the code that I felt was relevant to this question:

```
Private Sub ScreenerCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ScreenerCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Website As String = "https://www.ftportfolios.com/Broker/SalesTools/Morningstar/MorningstarToolsMain.aspx"
    Dim UserID As String = "Username"
    Dim Pword As String = "Password"

    If ScreenerCheckBox.Checked = True Then

        ScreenerWebBrowser.Visible = True

        With ScreenerWebBrowser
            .Navigate(Website)
        End With

        holdScreenBrowser()

        Timer1.Stop()

        Dim UserNameTextBox As HtmlElement = ScreenerWebBrowser.Document.All.Item("ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_txtLoginName")
        Dim PasswordTextBox As HtmlElement = ScreenerWebBrowser.Document.All.Item("ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_txtPassword")
        UserNameTextBox.InnerText = UserID
        PasswordTextBox.InnerText = Pword

        ScreenerWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_btnLogin").InvokeMember("click")

        WaitForScreenLoad()
        Timer1.Stop()

        ScreenerWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAccept").InvokeMember("click")

        WaitForScreenLoad()
        Timer1.Stop()

        ScreenerWebBrowser.DocumentText = IO.File.ReadAllText("https://www.ftportfolios.com/Broker/SalesTools/Morningstar/MorningstarToolsMain.aspx")

    Else
        With ScreenerWebBrowser
            .Visible = False
            .Navigate("about:blank")
            .Refresh()
        End With

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ScreenerWebBrowser_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles ScreenerWebBrowser.ProgressChanged
    On Error Resume Next
    If e.CurrentProgress = -1 Then
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    End If
    If e.CurrentProgress > 0 And e.MaximumProgress > 0 Then
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.CurrentProgress / e.MaximumProgress
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub holdScreenBrowser()
    On Error Resume Next
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    sec2 = 0
    Timer1.Start()
    Do While ScreenerWebBrowser.IsBusy Or ScreenerWebBrowser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    If sec2 >= 15 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ScreenerWebBrowser.Navigate("about:blank")
        ScreenerWebBrowser.Refresh()
        MsgBox("Sorry, the Application had some trouble loading the screener.  This can be caused by an interruption in the internet connection or a problem with the web server. Please try again after a few minutes.", vbExclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
Private Property ScreenerReady As Boolean = False
Public Sub WaitForScreenLoad()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Start()
    AddHandler ScreenerWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    While Not ScreenerReady
        Application.DoEvents()
        If sec2 >= 15 Then
            Form6.Hide()
            Timer1.Stop()
            ScreenerWebBrowser.Navigate("about:blank")
            ScreenerWebBrowser.Refresh()
            MsgBox("Sorry, the Application had some trouble loading the screener.  This can be caused by an interruption in the internet connection or a problem with the web server. Please try again after a few minutes.", vbExclamation)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End While
    ScreenerReady = False
End Sub
Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If ScreenerWebBrowser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        ScreenerReady = True
        RemoveHandler ScreenerWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code will load the website, login & accept the terms, but my combobox will not select any of the options in the combobox in the website.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After further review I've since discovered the site has several frames, and the combobox I want to manipulate is within one of the frames, I'll need to figure a way to locate it.